# Basement Bathroom Venting Help

Tags: bathroom, vent

[image]Our basement has been roughed in for a bathroom. My layout has a three floor PVC pipes coming out of the ground. The left most pipe has a tipped over bucket cemented onto the floor. There is a middle pipe at 2.5 inches and a 1.5 inch all the way to the right.

I'm GUESSING the toilet is the left most, not sure what is under the bucket, but maybe preventing the smell? There is a a plastic capped PVC pip coming down from the ceiling labeled 'BATH VENT' between the middle and right most PVC pipe.

If I would like a shower/toilet/sink in this space, does only the sink need to be attached to that overhead vent, or do all 3?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. The diagram helps, but  pictures would  be even more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to venture a guess here (at least until photos come). 2.5" isn't a pipe size so I'm going to go out on a limb and call it 3 inch that will be for your toilet. Regarding the bucket I'm going to guess that only a bottom half of the bucket is showing which means that there is a space in there to put a trap for a shower or tub. If the previous statements are correct then the one and a half inch pipe is really a 2"  which is a wet vent for your sink.

**In the floor it would look somewhat like this**[image]**www.doityourself.com**

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Daniel, pictures and measurements of distance between fixtures would help. If they are all aligned like this, yes you could tie all three into the common vent and be good to go.  The toilet will need a vent, most commonly wet vented to the nearest fixture by at least a 3" vent. Add some pics and more details.